# Is it possible to change the Color Space of Project Settings in C# of Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, there is an item of Project Settings → Player → Other Settings → ColorSpace.

I want to switch this Color Space between Linear and Gamma while the game is running.

Is it possible to do this in-game in C# or some other way?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Class `PlayerSettings` and its property `colorSpace` belongs to `UnityEditor` namespace, so they can only be used in Editor. `UnityEditor` namespace cannot be referenced by runtime code compiled into players, according to Unity Documentation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEditor.html